# Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, migration, moderator-abilities

It has happened on occasion, due to the high amount of 10K moderators on SO that questions are migrated to the wrong site, and needs to be reversed. Although currently it is possible to re-open the question on the original site and delete the one on the destination site, it still leave the migrated too banner behind.

It would be useful if diamond moderators could reverse a migration, removing it from the destination site completely and re-activating it on the original site and at the same time removing the banners.

Previously it has been discussed educating the users around when to move questions, however this doesn't stop the problem.

**As per Shog9**

I have to admit I do like Shog9's suggestion regarding the post being closed as not programming related rather then re-opened, however, reasons for closing it on other sites should also be kept in mind, as this also applies to stuff being sent back forth between the sites.

Comment: Is this your way of saying: don't give us all your SO crap! ;-)

Comment: You could say that. However it also happens with question from SF and I am sure it happens the other way around as well, although it is not often that questions are migrated on SU without a diamond mod being involved.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... sort of.

It's now possible to reject a migration, but rather than making this some special mod-only thing or yet another privilege/task you have to familiarize yourself with, it's instead a function of closing/deleting.

If a migrated question is closed **on the destination (migration target) site** as anything *other than* "exact duplicate" or "belongs on another site" (but not generic "off topic") it will result in the migration being **rejected**.  If a migrated question is deleted, it will also be **rejected**.

When a question is rejected:

- it's unlocked (but not reopened) on the source site
- any answers that were deleted as part of the migration are undeleted on the source site
- all migrated answers are deleted and locked on the destination site
- the migrated questions are locked on the destination site

Comment: would "bounced-back" question get any indication that there was an attempt to migrate at all? I ask because if not, this seem to put "destination" site at risk of getting it migrated again, due to same mistake as at prior attempt

Comment: @gnat - it's in the revision history, and the post is still closed so there's no way to re-migrate it without first re-opening it.

Comment: I see, thanks. Ie, only if post is later re-opened, and gets close-votes again, and close-voters don't look into revision history, **only then** repeated migration is possible right?

Comment: Could we get a 10k tools page that lists these *bounce backs*?

Comment: @gnat - yes, and by that point some flags are getting auto-raised about the close/reopen war (which is existing behavior).

Comment: Does the post get bumped on the source site at time of bounceback?

Comment: @BenBrocka - no, it doesn't.

Comment: But if the question is locked on the destination site, doesn't that mean it will stick around forever (on the would-be destination)? Locked means it won't be [auto-deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), and I don't think people could vote to delete it either.

Comment: Praise be! I've been hoping for this for a long time.

Comment: The thing I'd change is is the undeletion of *all* answers.  Moderators/10K'ers delete certain answers before migrating.  If that migration is rejected, then the answers the moderator deleted before moving the question over should *stay deleted* as they weren't answers to begin with.  Why duplicate the work?

Comment: @lunboks I assume it's locked/invisible just like migrated posts are on the source site, but I'd like to know for sure too

Comment: Filed bug report on the whole undeleting answers when rejecting the migration here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127093/when-migrations-are-rejected-do-not-undelete-answers-that-were-not-deleted-as-a - Note there's *two* bugs, given that deleting and undeleting the rejected migration re-deletes that which was deleted before the migration occurred.

Comment: I suggest bounceback not work where the two sites in question are (in either order) a site and its meta. (Except SO and MSO.) This, because the two sites in question have the same community (in theory) and the same mods (even in practice).

Comment: uhh I failed to reject a migrate when using the NC and NARQ close reasons, those are supposed to migrate, right?

Comment: @Ben - gonna need a link to investigate, what'd you close?

Comment: @KevinMontrose deleted: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19518/color-that-fits-with-3f5971-for-a-web-application another user says they saw the closed question on our site after I closed, but the answers were gone; I didn't manually delete the answers. Sounds like migration gone weird

Comment: @Ben looks correct to me, the answers were deleted and locked, the question was closed and locked, the [source question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961138/color-that-fits-with-3f5971-for-a-web-application) has been unlocked, it's answers undeleted.  History was recorded properly too, on the source site.  Am I missing something, it is pretty late (for me).

Comment: @KevinMontrose it was sill visible on our front page...is that supposed to happen? non-mod users could see it, I figured rejecting the migration would remove them visually as well

Comment: @Ben - ah no, there's still listed (unless actually deleted naturally).  They probably shouldn't be (will have to talk to the team about edge cases), sort of historical interest-style... I'll look into getting that figured out next week.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Ah...I was expecting a more visual indication that the migration was in fact rejected. So the question lives on both sites, but the answers only live on the migration source when rejected?

Comment: @Ben there is clear indication in the /revisions of the question. [Example](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/63132/revisions)

Comment: @Kevin looks like not all moderators are aware of this - [see here for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128066/unable-to-leave-a-comment-on-a-closed-question) - maybe add some warning before closing migrated question on its target site at least for the time being?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd in this case there was no link to the revisions on the question (it wasn't edited). I'll remember to check the /revisions next time though

Comment: @Ben cheers, but still - having one action cause major impact is something that need some alert, in my opinion.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd completely agreed, the process doesn't make much sense as is. Which is why I just deleted a question when migrating it back...it looked just like a normal, totally off topic/bad closed question

Comment: I'm a little confused by the last two bullet points - is there any difference between them? Does the last point refer to answers on the migrated question that were posted on the destination site?

Comment: Migrated posts are eventually deleted on the original site. When such a migration is rejected, is the post supposed to become undeleted?

Comment: @Kevin bump... see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193966/152859) as well please; so is it true that the questions on the target site remain locked forever when the migration is rejected?

Answer (score 56):

If the SO community says it doesn't belong on SO, then it would be a bit rude for you to override that: you're not a SO moderator.

However, I *would* be in favor of a feature that let you delete the question from your site and simultaneously *change the close reason to "off-topic" on SO* (in the process *unlocking* the original but leaving it closed). That would accomplish three helpful things:

1. It would get the question off of your site.
2. It would allow the question to be **re-opened** on SO, *if the people so desired*.
3. It would allow the question to be **deleted** on SO, if the people so desired.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the fact that migrated questions get locked. Besides what you said, it often keeps normal users from destroying `belongs-on-*` tags.

Comment: I like your idea. The reason I posted this on meta was to get a better solution then just sending it back. I don't agree completely with your answer but I really like the idea.

Comment: What are @Jeff's ideas on this one?

Comment: +1 - I'd go one step further and let any user with enough rep to vote to close have the option to vote something as a bad migration / "should have been closed", but this seems like a viable option.

Comment: You know what else it should do? It should automatically notify everybody who voted for the migration and tell them to read the FAQ on the target site, and not to do it again. And if they vote for 3 bad migrations to a particular site, they aren't allowed to vote for migrations to that site in the future. EVER. AGAIN.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. If it's migrated from SO, it didn't really belong there.  While it might be irrelevant to SU or SF too, you have the option to close or delete it. There's just no point in sending it back! Just kill it there.

#### Clarification

I agree with the removing the migration banner part. I'm just not fond of migrating things back.

Comment: Correction, it *most likely* doesn't below there, the community (maybe as few as 2 members) isn't *always* right, we have question skimmers and people with no expertise in the topic (and so don't understand the question) voting to close because *at a glance* it looks like it doesn't belong.  *Most* of the time you're correct, but it's not 100%.

Comment: Sending it back to SO gives the SO mods a learning experience, so they're more careful in future migrations.