# Need to be able to close as 'Belongs on Web Applications'

Tags: bug, status-deferred, vote-to-close, migration

The close reasons need to be updated to include the new website.

Going forward, how will this be handled when we have hundreds of sites?  I don't want to deal with a drop down that has more than a few possibilities...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

Comment: This might need to be closed as a duplicate of [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/289691)

Answer (score 5):

How so? the site hasn't proven it will survive private or public beta thresholds.

So, at best, this is premature.

edit: we do have new question migration paths but I don't think webapps is a valid path from Stack Overflow -- unless you can cite more than a trickle of closed questions that belonged there.

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:status-deferred]. I don't know when it was tagged this way, as this answer is the top answer, I think that it's worth saying, as [webapps.se] is 13 years old,  this answer is obsolete.

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst From the edit history and timestamps you can see the tag was added eight seconds after this answer was posted on Jul 1, 2010.

Comment: @Anyon Thanks. It looks like this have slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct current answer is to mark it for closure as off topic.

If you feel kind, point to the correct other place to ask the question. I agree though, more than 3 or 4 places to vote to move something is going to turn me off from voting to move things there. I liked the idea that came up elsewhere of requiring some level of rep on the target system before you could initiate a vote to move a question there.

Comment: Note the close box was recently revamped so other sites are sub-choices of the off-topic reason: votes for migrating are now also formally off-topic votes.

Comment: Yes. That's the point. It works fine when there are 4 options, but it won't work fine at all when there are 10, or 20, or 50.

Comment: I take it back. After the server migration, there don't seem to be any options for where to migrate a question.

Comment: They've never been here at Meta :)

Comment: The close reasons have changed, I think that a couple of times since 2010, so this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score -6):

As of July 15th, 2023 this question is tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) + [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

I don't think that "belongs to {{community}}" should be a close reason because there are overlapping across SO Inc. public Q&A platform communities, i.e., questions about Microsoft Excel formulas might be asked in

- Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Web Applications, if the question is about using one Excel online or it's related to a web application.
- ...

On the other hand, nowadays it is possible to migrate questions, ref. [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/1359324).