# Asking Questions on Stackoverflow vs GameDevelopment stackexchange

Tags: discussion, questions

Since the new GameDevelopment stackexchange beta https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ just came out today. When asking questions about game development should i only post them on the new website. I feel like it would be bad to double post. But since not everyone knows about the new site yet I feel as though I would get better responses here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question has to do with actual code, like "Why is this piece of code only producing 2 enemey AIs at a time?", then Stack Overflow is the better choice.

If your question is conceptual in nature, like "[What is a good algorithm for generating mazes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/910/algorithm-for-generating-a-2d-maze)", then Game Developers seems to be the better choice.

Regardless, please don't post a question on both sites. If the wrong site is chosen, it is better to have it on only one site, because a migration is better than a migration *and* a merge, and centralizing answers is better than diffusing them.

Comment: Can we migrate from core sites to Exchanges, or are we talking about a manual migration? (Also, fancy seeing you here again xD)

Comment: @Matchu See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

Comment: One I recognize that I posted in the wrong place (*i.e.*, a "what's a good algorithm for...?" question on SO), how do I go about migrating it?  if I'm low-rep, do I have to solicit the migration from someone higher-up?

Answer (score 4):

From a vague look over the GameDev Stack Exchange, I feel that it deals more with questions of concepts (how can I build random dungeons?) rather than questions of the nitty-gritty details of programming (why is my random-dungeon-building code not working?).

That said, the lines are blurry, and may or may not become clearer as the GameDev site continues to grow. I imagine you won't get in trouble either way, so post where you feel you'll get the best response. But try to pick one, since it likely is either concept or code, and the community will politely point you in the right direction if you quite obviously chose wrong :)

Comment: *"post where more appropriate... or on both,"* I would not suggest purposely cross posting "on both." Pick the site you think has the most appropriate audience. If you choose wrong, then it might be appropriate to bring your question to another audience.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - meh. I didn't feel like being the one to set a hard-and-fast rule, especially since this is likely one of the first times when two communities *really* had potential to cross over, so I took the "only if desperate" stance, instead. But if a mod says it, that's different :)

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - Oh, and I also just noticed that you were responding to a version that had a slightly different tone, since I was probably editing at the moment you were commenting xD ESP wins the day, I suppose. Regardless, question moved to an even less wishy-washy version 3.

Comment: Your current wording sounds like a reasonable approach to me.

Answer (score 4):

We had this [discussion on the GameDev meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow) and the consensus (based on the votes) basically boiled down to:

> Ask your question on GameDev even if its programming related **if** a game developer would give a different answer to your question than other programmers.

So if your question is about a specific game API or about something where priorities would be different for game development (in a game you might trade off some accuracy for performance, even though the "right" answer from a general programming perspective might be the more "accurate" one). But if your question is about a general programming question but it just happens to be for use in a game (say sorting an array), then SO is your best bet.

That being said, the community is still young, so if you find you don't get a satisfactory answer, then by all means fall back to SO (the GameDev community may yet evolve to a more purely theoretical one).

Answer (score -1):

If it's **both** programming and game development related I feel you can do any of the following:

- Post it only on stack overflow
- Post it only on game development
- Post it on both

Comment: is this the duplication that we're trying to prevent?