# How can I change a site the question is on?

Tags: support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

I've asked question and get comment that it will be better to ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com/. How can I move my question to this? I want avoid to duplicate.

Comment: Is there a feature request pending for global migration between all SE sites?

Comment: Not an "exact duplicate" per se, but since your question seems to be about the new SE sites, this feature request contains your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can vote to migrate a question to another site in the trilogy ([SO](http://stackoverflow.com), [SU](http://superuser.com), [SF](http://serverfault.com), and [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)), but currently there's no way to migrate a question to one of the SE sites like tex; you'll need to repost it manually. Usually people just mention in the question that it was originally posted on SO, and include a link to the original question