# Migrate to [Stack Exchange site] option

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, migration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can SO/SF/SU questions be migrated to beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60407/can-so-sf-su-questions-be-migrated-to-beta-sites)
>   [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

I'd like to suggest a migrate to Stackexchange site option, as suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796615/why-are-there-so-many-programming-languages-and-why-are-new-ones-still-being-inv

Expand the comments. It's in there.

You can migrate to the trilogy sites from any of the other two. A lot of questions from SO and SU may be more specific or more on topic on Apple.SE or Programmers.SE.

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your request

Comment: Juan - what do you mean? Popular Demand - it's not a dupe. That's a question, this is a direct request. There's a difference. :)

Comment: @Moshe, read Jeff's answer to that question. All of the non-beta SE sites already support migration.

Comment: I'd say that the answer still applies.  Migration paths won't be defined until sites are out of public beta.

Comment: The correct dupe is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65825/migrate-to-stack-exchange-site-option

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan) -- this is the actual `[status-planned]` feature request.