# Allow Beta sites to migrate questions to relevant sites

Tags: feature-request, migration, beta-sites

This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/what-monitors-have-larger-than-hd-resolution-size-is-less-important-closed) should have been migrated to Super User, but it can't be because there is no migration path.  Please setup migration paths for Beta's to relevant sites.

Comment: Only graduated sites get migration paths.  I'll look for the dupe.

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60407/can-so-sf-su-questions-be-migrated-to-beta-sites

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan

Comment: @rchern That's the opposite direction

Comment: Well, neither are exact dupes (but they're both related) so I don't feel too bad.  I'm sure we'll see a `status-declined` tag on this soon enough.

Comment: @Michael, the question title maybe, but Jeff's answer applies to both.  And really, if a path is defined one way, chances are it will be defined the other way.

Comment: Didn't see this question before I posted this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/455/can-we-get-new-migration-paths-setup

Comment: The unwanted junk at NPR would also be closed as off-topic on SU. @the

Comment: Jeff already [made it clear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60407/can-so-sf-su-questions-be-migrated-to-beta-sites) that migration won't be supported on beta sites. There's really nothing else to say about it.

Answer (score 4):

Beta sites should continue the sludge work on figuring out what is and what isn't on-topic.

Until then, the diapers need to stay on and any of that migration pathway criss-cross jumping around limited to nothing.

That question, [What monitors have larger than HD resolution? Size is less important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/what-monitors-have-larger-than-hd-resolution-size-is-less-important-closed) is all about helping some user with their shopping. A field of question off-topic for Super User.

Not every question fits.