# Enable automatic migration to any stackexchange site

Tags: feature-request, migration, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

Currently I can close questions on SO, SU and SF with "belongs on serverfault/stackoverflow/superuser.com".

I suggest adding an option to migrate to *all* relevant stackexchange sites.  For instance, a question on gmail should go on webapps.stackechange.com, a question on using android phones should go to android.stackechange.com and a subjective programming question should go on programmers.stackexchange.com.  Currently, I can't do that automatically.