# There is No "Belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com" Migration Path

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

A lot of questions on SO can be closed as "belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com". However, this path never does exist.

Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: See [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan/54524#54524) about when SE sites will be added to "belongs on..." list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, this can only be implemented when programmers is out of beta.

Comment: Is programmers.stackexchange.com out of beta now? (I don't see any beta badging) and I certainly see questions that would ideally be bounced there like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019811/yii-when-to-use-widgets

Answer (score 6):

1. Migration paths don't exist where the target site is still in beta (which Programmers is at this point).
2. Migration paths will only be set up if there is evidence that they will be useful (which there is in this case).
3. This is already under discussion - see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71731/59303)
4. There is a limit to the number of migration paths - see [this question on Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/q/1595/289)