# Add close as belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com to stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, close-reasons

Now that [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is [out of beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/), can we get the "close as belongs on" added for it to StackOverflow?

See also: [There is No "Belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com" Migration Path](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71898/there-is-no-belongs-on-programmers-stackexchange-com-migration-path).

I'm re-asking since that was apparently asked before the site got out of beta and was marked as a bug report (status-by-design).

Comment: I know I'd use it :)

Comment: We also need the reverse migration for programming questions asked on Programmers.

Comment: This would fill up the last free spot (Jeff has stated that it will be limited to five sites), so maybe we should consider [selecting the destination sites based on the question tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)?

Comment: As long as users don't go mass migrating questions to Programmers, while not knowing it's scope well enough. If it's too subjective for SO, it probably will be on Programmers too!

Comment: This ought to be asked at meta.p.se first, see what they think about it.  I guess that would invoke a pretty strong No!  Just a guess.

Comment: @Hans - why? Programmers was specifically created to address questions being asked on SO that didn't belong there.  In fairness, I suppose that there ought to be a reciprocal arrangement but I don't spend much time at programmers.se so that is less important to me.

Comment: @Ivo - then I suppose the SO team ought to do a good job with the descriptive text for the close reason to minimize this.  We should be able, though, to migrate those questions that programmers.se was designed to accept.

Comment: I guessed, lots of angst in the past that I tuned out.  I suspect Ivo is close, meta.p.se would know the real why.

Comment: It has been added but is still mod-only to prevent possible abuse.

Comment: @Michael -- that's funny, I can see it and I'm not a moderator.

Comment: Ha, you're right. That target must have been added in the last couple of days. What moderators get is a special tool to migrate to *any* Stack Exchange site, including all meta sites.

Answer (score 3):

[image: belongs on programmers]

I was about to ask the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was just going to start flagging questions until the moderators got tired of doing it manually and pressured the devs to spend some coding time to fix it. :-)

Comment: We can't do it any more than you can. Right now, only people with DB access can.

Comment: leave the mods alone!  I think it's already been taken up with the devs.

Comment: @Michael Myers Yea, that's why I said, until you guys pressured the devs to get it done. Your word has substantially more weight than my word does. :-)