# Flagging off topic questions (dba specific)

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

I flagged a question today that was not a programming question but a database server configuration question.  After clicking off-topic I was asked where it should go instead.  I picked serverfault but in reality thought it would be better over at dba.stackexchange.com .

Is this not on the list because it is still in beta?

More importantly, what is the best way to flag questions that should be at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: A migration path will most likely not be added to dba.stackexchange.com, even after it comes out of beta. More information is available [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange). As Lance says, the workaround is to flag the question for moderator attention. Moderators can migrate questions anywhere in the network, regardless of whether or not the site is "unlocked" and appears in the list of choices.

Answer (score 7):

We take care when migrating anything with our super vote, however we're *especially* careful when migrating questions that aren't in a site's normal migration path. We need to ensure that the following holds true:

- The question is, indeed off topic for Stack Overflow
- The question is, indeed on topic for the target site - according to their FAQ

Otherwise, we're ensuring that someone who put time and thought into a question (moderators don't migrate crap questions) has a bad experience, and that's not what we want to do. When it comes to migrations, we like the community to handle them - unless we're intervening to stop a bad migration. That's not possible when going out of the normal migration path, which is why we're especially careful.

You should flag the post in question to let us know, but be sure to indicate that you are a member of the receiving community and feel the question fits within your FAQ. Additionally, it *really* helps us if the author of the question also flags to indicate that they'd like to have their question migrated.

Of course, there are clear cut cases where we'd immediately agree with you.

Keep in mind, if a question *is* appropriate for Stack Overflow, we're *not* going to migrate it unless the owner of the question asks us to do so. Their choice of posting on SO might be strategic, or perhaps they simply aren't interested in joining another site.

Comment: Err, Cody said it *won't* be added (to SO). That said, I could see SF --> dba.se.

Comment: @Jon indeed you are correct! Editing. Decongestants seem to do funny things to me.

Comment: `Warning: do not take this medication and drive, operate heavy machinery, or moderate a Stack Exchange site.`

Comment: @Jon The non drowsy is a _lie_.

Comment: "Moderators don't migrate crap questions" - demonstrably false.

Answer (score 1):

Flag it for the moderator and ask them to migrate it to the right site.

Comment: When selecting "off topic" it gives a list of sites where it should go.  dba.stackexchange.com is not on the list.

Comment: Instead of "off topic" should I select "other" and then describe.

Comment: @lazyDBA, yes, that's how you flag it for a moderator.