# How do I vote to migrate questions to other SE sites that aren't listed?

Tags: support, questions, migration, close-reasons

When I vote to close a question because it is off topic, the only other SE I can recommend the question to are the following 5:

[image]

In this instance I feel the question should have been posted at wordpress.stackexchange.com, but I have no way to suggest this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Flag them for ♦ moderator attention.** Moderators can migrate a question to any site in the Stack Exchange network, regardless of whether the migration path has been unlocked on the current site.

When flagging, choose the "other" option so that you can specify which other site you think the question should be migrated to and *why* you think it's a good fit for that site. For example:

[image: Flag for moderator attention because "This question would be a better fit on cstheory.stackexchange.com, as it asks for a security review of already-working code."]

(Related: [Option to move post from Stackoverflow to codereview.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange))

Comment: Note that migrating to beta sites is generally discouraged.  I believe Rebecca told me that but I can't recall exactly why.

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, it's generally discouraged so that the beta community can define their own notions of what is/is not on-topic and the community there can contribute their own content. That's one of the reasons why this is a moderator-only decision: moderators are expected to confirm the migration with the moderators on the target site. *Some* high quality questions can usefully be migrated to a beta site, and it's not unusual for *new* questions to get migrated there, where they might get a better answer.

Comment: Bah! I just noticed that I completely mistyped the suggested migration site in my demo message. That should be Code Review, not CS Theory... Oh well, I don't feel like changing it now.

Comment: @CodyGray: Does the system note when the suggestion comes from a user that's active on the suggested target site?  I feel like I have a good sense of what belongs on http://askubuntu.com/ vs. what belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/, for example.  (I haven't been voting to migrate shell/sed/awk questions from SO to unix, though, because there are too many to spam the moderators with.)