# How can I vote for a question to be migrated to math.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I vote to migrate questions to other SE sites that aren't listed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102436/how-do-i-vote-to-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites-that-arent-listed)

There are questions on Stack Overflow that are pure math questions that should be migrated to the math Stack Exchange. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433371/ellipse-bounding-a-rectangle). However, these are the only options:

> belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com Q&A for the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites
>   belongs on serverfault.com Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals
>   belongs on superuser.com Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users
>   belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com Q&A for pro webmasters
>   belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development

There needs to be a way to move questions to other Stack Exchange sites that are not limited to a static set.

Comment: Yeah, I looked but could not find anything. Close as dupe.

Comment: There's a lot of similar questions already, I think. The problem is they're tricky to find as they're all asked in terms of *specific* SE 2.0 sites. I cheated on finding that one because I knew I'd answered it. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jeff [has stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/96345#96345) that there will only ever be 5 migration paths on the close dialog and one of those has to be the site's meta. That leaves 4 other slots which are all currently filled.

If you wanted one of these replaced you would have to come up with compelling evidence that there were more questions that needed to be migrated to Maths than one of the existing 4.

However, all is not lost. Moderators can migrate to any site in the network so simply **flag the question for moderator attention** explaining why you think it should be migrated and they'll do the rest.

[image]

Comment: It is not an optimal solution, but I guess it works.