# What to do with off-topic questions that would be perfect for a beta site

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I vote to migrate questions to other SE sites that aren't listed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102436/how-do-i-vote-to-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites-that-arent-listed)

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812639/does-this-look-like-a-good-solution-to-a-javascript-countdown-without-using-php), and I think that it should really be in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, flagging a question as off topic doesn't allow me to recommend the site where this question belongs, as it does with non-beta sites. Is it correct to still flag as off-topic here?