# Can we flag questions to be migrated to Public Beta or even Area 51 proposals?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

Or, in other words: How mature site must be, for other sites' question could be flagged to be migrated to this one?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102436/how-do-i-vote-to-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites-that-arent-listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've flagged for migration to public beta sites (namely from Stack Overflow to Code Review), but proposals don't exist as a site yet, so those can't be migrated to.