# Can we move questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration

I came across a few questions that should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.

Is it possible to move the question directly from Stack Overflow to Code Review? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flag them for ♦ moderator attention.** Moderators can migrate a question to any site in the Stack Exchange network, regardless of whether the migration path has been unlocked on the current site.

When flagging, choose the "other" option so that you can specify which other site you think the question should be migrated to and *why* you think it's a good fit for that site.

(Related: [Option to move post from Stackoverflow to codereview.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange))