# Add a "more" link to the Close as Off Topic window so we can migrate to *all* Stack Exchange sites.*

Tags: feature-request, migration

I decided [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750300/how-did-the-term-slug-as-in-urls-originate) was off topic, so I voted to close. The problem is that I closed it as off topic and I thought it would be better suited on English Language & Usage.

However, I couldn't choose that (English Language & Usage) in the pop-up.
[image: example]

I think there should be a "more" link in the bottom of the pop-up when someone wants to close a question as off-topic so it could be migrated to a site not already listed. If a site in the "more" section would already have a vote to get the question migrated to there, it would be listed without the need to click "more".

Is there a reason this is not yet implemented?

---

<sub><sup>* except perhaps beta sites</sup></sub>

Answer (score 8):

Related: [Will it be possible to migrate questions between the trilogy and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan)

It's very rare that a question on Stack Overflow needs to be migrated to English.SE. It's even more rare that it'd need to be migrated to something like Cooking.SE or Gardening.SE. Having users choose from all possible SE sites doesn't make sense, since most of those sites would never see a migration.

In addition to that, it's unreasonable to expect every user with the "vote to close" privilege to be familiar with the scope of every other Stack Exchange site. Limiting the number of migration paths allows the most common migrations to happen without moderator intervention and even then we sometimes see "bad" community-driven migrations.

If you see a question that needs to be migrated to a site that doesn't have a default migration path, flag the question for moderator attention instead of voting to close. If the question belongs on the suggested destination, a moderator will move it.

Comment: It's not _that_ rare. People are likely to ask for software recommendations, for example. Also, declaring it rare is a self-fulfilling prophecy since the dialog doesn't have the appropriate option :-)

Comment: @einpoklum You know this answer is 5.5 years old, right? I didn't event *work* at SO at the time it was posted. ;) I still think it mostly holds up, though. We did launch more technical sites since, but if nothing else, the third paragraph still applies. We'd need to look at recent data for recent flags asking for migration that were actually performed vs what's available in the close dialog to see if the options there still hold up. Wouldn't be the first time the available options were tweaked.

Comment: @einpoklum Having said that, in your specific example, just because a question asks for a software rec doesn't mean it's a good migration to Software Recommendations SE. That site works largely because they have fairly specific standards. Opening up the floodgates of "migrated from Stack Overflow" could have pretty serious implications for a smaller site (and we've seen that happen before as well, back when Software Engineering was first launched).

Comment: ♦: (1) It's not _necessarily_ a good migration to SR.SE, but it's _often_  a good migration, certainly not _rare_ (2) A lot of questions asked on SR.SE do not initially meet the standards, and get fixed or refined after comments.