# Make how to migrate questions to unlisted SE sites more obvious

Tags: feature-request, migration

There have been several requests to add various sites to the Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migrate list ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99021/add-a-more-link-to-the-close-as-off-topic-window-so-we-can-migrate-to-all-st?rq=1), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112345/should-dba-stackexchange-com-be-an-option-when-closing-off-topic-questions), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159604/why-close-as-off-topic-does-not-have-an-option-to-migrate-to-programmers-stack), ...), or [asking why not all sites are listed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited), or [suggesting a "more" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99021/add-a-more-link-to-the-close-as-off-topic-window-so-we-can-migrate-to-all-st). I won't rehash those, and I'm not suggesting any of those things. I *am* suggesting something similar, but different.

Apparently, if you think a question belongs on another SE site but it isn't listed, you're supposed to use a moderator flag. From [this answer by Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/134069):

> ...flag the question for moderator attention, with a comment specifying which site the question should be moved to, and we will migrate it if it is appropriate to do so.

A long-time SO user, this surprised me. I had no idea that was the standard of practice.

Let's make that A) more obvious, and B) easier to automate by adding an "other" option where you can **type in** the URL of the site to migrate it to.

This would in the short term be the moderator flag saying you think it should go to site X (e.g., the answer from Robert above), and in the long-term if (say) a majority of close-voters type in the same site, could be automated.

Making people actually type the URL, rather than picking from a list, addresses the concern (also noted in [Robert's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/134069)) of people migrating to other sites based purely on the other site's name; to know the site's URL, you have to know *something* about it. But makes it simpler to do what you're currently supposed to do, and hopefully eventually lightening the load on our overloaded moderators.

Gratuitous UI mockup:

[image: Belongs on Other]

Comment: You've linked to a whole bunch of posts explaining why we *don't* want this.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think I have, if you read carefully. I'm trying to make the **existing** mechanism clearer, and potentially automate it. Read again what those posts are asking for.

Comment: I looked through a few again, just to be sure what you chose to link, out of all of the posts suggesting something similar, addressed problems with this proposal, and most of them had points that are equally applicable to this alteration.

Comment: Please, not more migration flags: they're wrong more often than not and time consuming to verify (check for cross posts, check target site FAQ, check for obvious dupes) even when correct.

Comment: @Flexo: Then we should do away with them entirely, not implicitly encourage people to shoe-horn questions onto a small list of sites. If migration doesn't make sense, it doesn't make sense. I could totally see that. Suggest the site, but *don't* migrate the question, make the questioner do the work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's allowed for the handful of situations in which it's both common and often successful.  It's *possible* in the situations that aren't common, but is intentionally not extensively advertised.  That's pretty much just what it should be.  There really isn't a reason to change it at all.

Comment: Like Flexo said, we currently have piles and piles of migration flags jamming up the moderator queue at the moment. The one positive thing I could see about this is if it would label these flags in such a way that they could be sorted out of the "other" flags we have now. One restriction I would apply would be to disallow migration flags like this to sites where the flagger has less than 110 points of reputation. We've found that most people who request migration to a site, but lack an active account there, really have no idea what's on topic there.

Comment: @BradLarson: *"One restriction I would apply would be to disallow migration flags like this to sites where the flagger has less than 110 points of reputation."* Oooh, I like that. That makes a great deal of sense. Is 110 high enough, given that 101 is basically the starting point for anyone in the network? Maybe 200? But the level is less important than the idea.

Comment: @Servy: *"That's pretty much just what it should be."* Sorry, just cannot agree there at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're looking to make it easier for you to migrate questions elsewhere.  You seem to not be considering all of the problems that this creates.  It's a *good thing* that there is some friction in the process because when there's not (and this has been objectively analyzed in the past) it causes a lot of bad migrations.  Making things easier for you, but much harder for others, is still a net harm to the site.

Comment: @Servy: If migrating questions is such a problem, it should be removed entirely, not half-removed, hidden, obscured, whatever. It's not *harder* to flag a question for moderator attention and say "this belongs on Fluglehorn.stackexchange.com" than it is to choose "other" above and type the same thing, it's just hidden.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why remove it for the cases where it's working just because there are cases where it doesn't work?  Why is that better than enabling it for the cases that have proven themselves as both common and successful and not emphasizing or streamlining the cases where it's either extremely uncommon, or with a bad track record?  Your proposed change makes it worse.

Comment: @Servy: You seem to believe that limiting migrations through obscurity (knowing to flag it for mods if not on the list) is a good idea. I don't. If we want only allow certain people to migrate questions (to certain destinations), we should (as Brad did) come up with objective criteria and apply them, rather than relying on people just not knowing what they should do. Obscure hidden functionality is by definition badly-implemented functionality. Now, I don't expect you to agree with that. You've been heard, I just disagree with you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't say it was idea.  I didn't say it couldn't possibly be improved on.  I said that removing it entirely is clearly worse.  If you think it could be improved then suggest an improvement that's actually better, rather than saying that because it does something you don't like it should be removed entirely, even though it's clearly adding value currently.  Obscuring functionality isn't also bad by definition.  It's a sign of poor practice, but that doesn't make it universally wrong, but rather a sign that it *might* be wrong.  Sometimes there just are no good options.

Comment: @Servy: I think our one-to-one discussion is no longer serving a useful purpose. We've both said what we're saying, and either been heard or not. Rather than say that *and* reply to the above, which seems like trying to steal the last word :-), I'll just leave it there. Best,

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this would be a cool way to automatically cast a moderator flag for migration  (we already do this with close votes).

We could use the same UI that the moderators have (I wouldn't bother with using URLs... I'm not convinced that just because someone knows the URL that they know something about the scope of the target site).

All that said, let me be a contrarian and say that migration is not ideal for most questions.  It's better if the OP goes to the correct site and reposts the question himself.  The migration process is too cumbersome; it takes too long because you have to involve a moderator, and migration should only be used with very high-quality questions anyway.

Comment: Exactly. The idea is that it clarifies and simplifies the existing process. (I thought it might eventually automate it, but it sounds like that wouldn't be the case.) I run into perfectly good questions that have been posted to the wrong place often enough I'd find it useful. I expect that to dramatically increase as [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) comes to life.