# When migrations are rejected, do not undelete answers that were not deleted as a result of a migration

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, migration-rejection

As a result of [the ability to "reject" a migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/140951) (through certain types of closure on the target site, or deletion on the target site), answers will be undeleted on the source site when a migration is rejected.

However, answers that are not deleted *before* the question is migrated are undeleted as well.

Take [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890350/test-of-new-migration-rejection) on Stack Overflow (links 10K only):

[image: migration and rejection]

However, take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890357/50776), which was deleted *before* migration took place:

[image: answer deleted before migration]

Which did *not* appear [on the target site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/141725/24941):

[image: deleted answer deleted on target site]

However, when the migration is rejected, the answer is undeleted.

Furthermore, if the question is deleted after the migration is rejected and then undeleted, the answer that was originally deleted gets undeleted (which is what I would expect when the migration is rejected).

So it seems that a check needs to be performed to make sure that answers that are deleted when migrated *remain* deleted when that migration is rejected.

Comment: Too many double-negatives in the title; my head hurts! :D

Comment: @AndrewBarber And we're surprised SE forces us to use so many double negatives because? =)

Comment: Yeah... seems an odd complaint, when I think about it! hehe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hmmm, the error here is not that they were undeleted, that was only a symptom.  If you look close, [those deleted-before-migration answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9890357/revisions) were getting migration history *though they weren't migrated*.  Since the "what do we undelete?" check has to key off this, it caused problems there.

The generation of migration history on answers that weren't really migrated will be fixed in the next build.