# Add a direct link for a user-initiated migration?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration

Once a user has discovered he has posted a question on the wrong site, it seems to me the usual solution that they arrive at is to simply cross-post it on the second site.

Even established users do this (I've just been discussing it with a 15k rep SO user).

Rather then having to:

1. flag for a moderator and explain you want it migrating
2. vote to close it and choose a new target (along with 4 other users?)
3. cross-post and delete the original

would it not be better to include a `migrate` (or `move`) link under the question, obviously only visible to the OP, and take them directly to the list of migration targets?

Comment: What's wrong with a flag? And how would this link change anything? A mod would still have to evaluate it, or users would have to agree with it. Unless I'm missing a point here....

Comment: I'm suggesting the link would just do the migration, not flag it for a mod. The OP is already able to delete his own question and repost, so it is not adding something they we basically can't do already, just making it easier

Comment: So the link would cause an auto-migration? I get it's not much different than deleting a question on one site and asking it on another, but somehow that does not seem like a great idea. At least when re-posting there might still be some thought by the OP to adapt it to the new site...

Comment: good point, even better would be not just migrate, but leave you on a page with the question open in 'edit' mode on the new site and a notice suggesting tailoring to the different audience

Comment: they'd have to be signed up for the new site along the way of course...

Comment: Simple and convenient ways for users To correct their mistakes?  never gonna happen here at SE.  Don't make mistakes in the first place!!!

Answer (score 1):

I oppose this. A lot of times, a user will recommend a site which the question is *not* suitable for. I've seen a lot of comments suggesting a question be asked on Programmers when it doesn't belong there.

Migration is a complex beast -- if a migration is rejected, it [creates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127093/when-migrations-are-rejected-do-not-undelete-answers-that-were-not-deleted-as-a) [some problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations). Plus, it's a PITA for the other site to take care of it.

I think the current way is fine, having users flag for migration isn't a big deal. Adding a big easy button for migration will increase the percentage of rejected migrations, IMO.

Comment: So in your experience are bad migrations worse than cross-posting? Perhaps we are lucky we don't get *many* bad migrations on dba.se (and it is very easy to reject them), but dealing with cross-postings takes a lot more mod time trying to get one of them migrated, then closing and merging the dupe.

Comment: @JackDouglas: That too, though in my experience most cross posts don't get time to be answered before they get closed. And ones without (good) answers only need to be closed, no need to migrate and merge.