# Rejected migration undeletes answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, deleted-answers, migration-rejection

#### Background

This seems to be the same bug as in [When migrations are rejected, do not undelete answers that were not deleted as a result of a migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127093), which is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

#### Bug

The migration of the question [How can you find out the date for the last accreditation for a web server?](https://superuser.com/q/48994) from SU to SF was rejected approximately an hour ago. The only answer had been deleted by the owner himself long before the migration occurred, but the recent rejection undeleted it.

#### Screenshots

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: The owner has re-deleted his answer by now. The second deletion does not appear in the revisions.

Answer (score 3):

The bug here was that for several years, all answers on a question would be marked as "migrated" - even if they weren't (say, because they were deleted).

The *other* bug here was that for about the same number of years the deletion date of all answers to a migrated question would be set to the timestamp of the migration. Again, even if they weren't migrated because they'd already been deleted years ago for some other reason.

Both of those bugs were fixed on March 27, 2012.

Unfortunately, that left a bunch of answers on migrated questions marked migrated with their deletion date set to the date of the migration. Even though they weren't migrated, they look pretty much the same as answers that *were* migrated.

This should be almost a non-issue now though, since most of these migrated stubs have long ago been automatically deleted - meaning even if the answers do get undeleted, they'll be re-deleted automatically soon afterwards.

Comment: Hi Shog, When the bug was fixed, why is this not [tag:status-completed] but by design?

Comment: Because there is still a small chance of encountering it due to bad data from prior to 2012, and if I document it as fixed then that's gonna be confusing, eh?