# Don't reverse migrations on deleted posts if they were merged first

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, merged-questions, migration-rejection

The recent change to [reject question migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982) broke a rather useful workflow when it came to cross-posted questions. When a cross-posted question is found, it's common for one site to keep it and the other to close (to avoid splitting answers):

- Site A migrates the cross-post to site B, which already has it (so now it has two)
- Site B closes the new question as a duplicate of the old one
- Site B deletes the migrated question

Since migrated posts and merged posts (even when deleted) automatically redirect users, this had the effect that users viewing the post on site A were redirected to the cross-posted version on site B. Now that procedure results in the post on Site A being recategorized as "off-topic". Supposedly that doesn't happen if the post was closed as an exact duplicate, so I think it happened when the migrated post was deleted, but I'm not sure

Can we skip reversing a migration if the deleted target post was merged first?

Comment: And before someone says that it's too bad and the asker shouldn't have cross-posted: the point is to be more helpful to future visitors by not leaving a dead end that has the question without its answers.

Comment: This should extend to mere "Close as duplicate". The migrators did everything right and we still reject the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually fixed back in 2013 with an explicit check for a merged state; we just forgot to update this meta post.

HOWEVER, as Raphael noted in the comments... Merges are really just a special case of a more general problem: questions closed as duplicates after being migrated still could not be deleted without rejecting the migration.

As of yesterday, that too is fixed: migrations will not be rejected upon deletion if the question is merged *or* closed as a duplicate.