# Unable to leave a comment on a closed question

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions

This question:

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/commit-suicide-in-a-literary-way

...was migrated to Writers, then closed. (I'm the moderator that closed it.) Unfortunately, I'm unable to leave a comment explaining why it was closed. I'm assuming this has something to do with the migration; the original question on EL&U no longer indicates it was migrated to Writers, just that it was closed. What's going on here? (I tried reopening it, that didn't help.)

Comment: Shouldn't it have been migrated to http://literature.stackexchange.com/ ? (not sure of this)

Comment: @Manishearth Neil is not the one who migrated it, just closed as off topic on the target site.

Comment: @Manishearth Actually no, the question has nothing to do with Literature.SE, check out [their FAQ](http://literature.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @ShaDow I know, I'm just saying that it may have made sense for him to migrate instead of close. Unless mutiple migrations aren't allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal as [reversing a migration locks the question on the target site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/162704):

> When a question is rejected:
>
> - it's unlocked (but not reopened) on the source site
> - any answers that were deleted as part of the migration are undeleted on the source site
> - all migrated answers are deleted and locked on the destination site
> - the migrated questions/answers are locked on the destination site

It's a bit confusing, as there's no hint that the question is locked, no lock notification and the vote arrows are still there. The only mention of the question's actual state is on [its timeline](https://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/5364/timeline) and the [revision history](https://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/5364/revisions).

Comment: http://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/5364/revisions and http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/63132/revisions showing the whole lock process made by Community user. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Thanks, added to the answer. There were no edits, hence no revision link, so I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Too much time here on Meta, lol.. it also clearly says "Migration Rejected" on the source question revisions. :)

Comment: Thanks! So how do I add a comment to the question? Just unlock it? Or will that cause some *other* nefarious problem? :) It's closed pending edits, but I can't leave a comment to that effect. (It's "off topic" because it needs more information to be a proper critique question.) The user has opened a meta.writers thread, and I'll address the issues there, but that's not very transparent or elegant.

Comment: @NeilFein I don't think you can, unless you re-open, comment and close again, but that's not really something I would do (and it might brake something, I don't know). You can always post a comment on the source site, explaining why you rejected the migration. Better yet you could provide a detailed answer to the Meta question, and post a comment with a link to it on the source question (also the user who asked the Meta question is not the OP).

Comment: Was able to unlock the question without re-opening. Thanks for the help, have accepted this as the answer.

Comment: @NeilFein Yes but... did you lock it again afterwards? And if yes, what lock category did you choose?

Comment: No, I didn't lock it because I want the user who wrote it to be able to comment and edit.