# Why cannot I vote to delete this closed question?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128936/what-is-the-website-where-you-can-build-a-demo-database-for-stackoverflow-questi has been closed, but I cannot vote to delete it, although I am a 20k user.

[image: screenshot]

I thought that 20k users can immediately vote to delete a closed question. Are there cases where this is not true? Is this caused by any recent change?

I don't even see the "edit" link, which I should see. What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Could this be related with the migration? That the migration was reverted? There was a question about that some time ago...wait, let me look for it...

Comment: Why is this off topic to begin with?  This question is basically asking "what is the data explorer".  It's not off topic, although it's likely a dupe.

Comment: @casperOne: I'd disagree...that user does not ask for the Data Explorer.

Comment: @Bobby Yeah, I see it now.  The language isn't the greatest.  The stackoverflow aspect is misleading as well.

Comment: Mh, damn, can't find it right now. But I can remember a similar case from a week ago where a Diamond(?) from a new site came over. Had the same or very similar issue with a migrated question. Turned out the migration was reverted behind the scenes.

Comment: Grrr… I wrote, "vote to close" when I meant "vote to delete." The question is already closed; therefore, I cannot vote to close it. `:)`

Comment: The question has been locked, that's why you can't delete it. So the real question is, why was it locked? And the answer is probably related to the migration, as others have suggested.

Comment: @TheEstablishment The real question could also be, "Why doesn't Stack Exchange show the notice about the post being locked?" `:)` I don't understand why, when the migration has been automatically rejected, 20k users cannot vote to delete the migrated question, but that is a different question.

Comment: I see my name, vanity upvote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is locked, as you can see in the [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/128936/revisions). It was locked by Community the moment it was closed.

I suspect the migration-rejection code did something funny here, as these questions shouldn't have been locked automatically.

Comment: No, it's working exactly [as designed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982). Rejected migrations are locked on the would-be destination. The design just makes no sense, because the question will now stick around forever unless a moderator sees to it.

Comment: I agree; I don't see why an off-topic question should be deleted just from the moderators. Is there any difference between an off-topic question asked in a site, and a question migrated from a different site, and considered off-topic in the receiving site? It works as reported in the other question, though.