# Show lock banners on rejected migrations

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, locked-questions, migration-rejection

When a migration [gets rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/131713), it gets locked automatically.

Auto-locking seems to be what happened with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473143/methods-to-stop-software-piracy. It behaves like a locked question and its [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1473143/revisions) notes that it's locked, that the lock was assigned by Community and that the assignment happened at the exact same moment the question was closed.

However, I don't see a "**locked by Community♦ Apr 22 at 20:13**" banner on the question page. I do see "**migrated from...**" and "**closed as...**" banners.

I think that all rejected migrations should have lock banners on the target site.

Comment: Thanks Jadarnel27 and Daniel Fischer for help tracking down what was going on with that lock!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implemented in build rev `2014.1.22.1980` on meta and `2014.1.22.1322` on sites. Next time you'll encounter a rejected migration on a target site you'll see a post notice like this:

[image: migration rejected notice]

Comment: Nice! While you're at it, what caused [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473143/methods-to-stop-software-piracy) to be deleted? It just says "deleted Apr 28 '12 at 2:52" and no delete event in its [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1473143/revisions). It even get weirder: all answer were deleted **20 minutes after the question was deleted**.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Can't say for sure, but I think it may be Roomba. In the past, Roomba deletions weren't attributed to the Community user, but to nobody. As far as the answers being deleted later, occasionally, there are some bugs that result in answers not being deleted at the same time as the question, but there is a scheduled task that runs that deletes non-deleted answers to deleted questions in case something weird happens and the answers aren't deleted at the same time.

Comment: @Sonic thanks, this does make sense.

Answer (score 11):

I think putting "locked" on these isn't terribly useful, since it doesn't tell you *why* it was locked. You can go into the revision history now and see that it's locked, but unless you recall that it was migrated and that closing rejects migrations, you're still left scratching your head wondering what Community♦'s smoking.

A banner to the effect of,

> #### Migration rejected from *link to question on originating site*

...would not only explain *what* happened, but give any passers-by a quick way to visit the question in its new (old) home.

Answer (score 8):

Yes please!

I've just come across my [first rejected migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502516/erd-of-real-estate-agency-website) since there's been something explicit saying that you can't comment on deleted/locked posts. It *seemed* like a bug; I'm suddenly unable to comment on a closed post?

[image]

There ought to be something here to explicitly indicate that the question is locked and stop simple old me from getting confused :-(.

Comment: The additional frustration is often that the answers are also deleted, leaving a locked question (that the roomba won't pick up), that has no answers visible to a non-10k, that the 10k can't cast a dv on.  The only thing to do is flag for a mod to come clean it up.