# Can't vote to delete migrated and subsequently closed questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, vote-to-delete, migrated-questions

As a 20k user, I am **not able to vote to delete** questions that have been migrated to the site, which were subsequently closed.

I've reproduced this with various questions, e.g. [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/430591/is-there-a-free-way-to-collaborate-over-a-single-text-file) or [that one](https://superuser.com/questions/431220/opening-a-port-to-make-a-connection-in-windows-7). No delete link for me. <sub>Not that I want to delete that particular question, just an example.</sub>

> [image]

According to my privileges, I should be able to vote to delete any question (regardless of its score and age) after it has been closed.

Comment: Migration could have been undone by the close-vote, so you only see a ...uuhhh...shadow-like copy on SU.

Answer (score 4):

That's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), [rejected migrations are locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/162704):

> When a question is rejected:
>
> - it's unlocked (but not reopened) on the source site
> - any answers that were deleted as part of the migration are undeleted on the source site
> - all migrated answers are deleted and locked on the destination site
> - the migrated questions/answers are locked on the destination site

However you'd need to check their revision history or timeline to find out, as they don't have a lock notice and the vote arrows are still there (but don't work). There's an [open feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations) to show lock notices on rejected migrations.

Comment: The question is why we shouldn't be able to delete them, since they're obviously *crap migrations*.

Comment: @slhck And the answer to that is that they are locked as Sha Dow Wiz Ard already mentioned (I answered only to point out it's by design), and regular users can't vote to delete locked questions. That said, they are a special kind of locked question, and they should probably be automatically deleted upon rejection, as, well, there isn't anything else anyone can do about them. I usually delete them as soon as they are closed on ProgSE.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is because the question is also locked, not just closed. (Note you don't have edit link as well and can't post comment)

(You can see this in the [revisions](https://superuser.com/posts/430591/revisions) page of the question)

So the question should actually be what caused the question to be locked? Smells like a bug though.

Comment: Interesting. That would explain it, but it still doesn't make sense why the question would need to be locked.

Comment: Maybe when migrated question get closed on the target site it also get auto lock to prevent further migrations? Dunno.. we need a dev here. :)