# Why can't I vote to delete a migrated question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, migrated-questions

A question was migrated away from Judaism.SE.  Now it is sitting in the archives of closed and locked questions, with an obsolete tag.  I want to delete it, and purge the obsolete tag from the face of the planet!  But (I assume because it is locked) I can't vote to delete it.

Why is a migrated question locked such that it can't be deleted on the site from which it was migrated?

Note: not a dupe of [Can't vote to delete migrated and subsequently closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134439/cant-vote-to-delete-migrated-and-subsequently-closed-questions) - I am asking about migrated from, not migrated to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Migrated questions get locked so that we don't end up with two different versions of one question on separate sites. The idea is to direct *all* activity for that question to the new site. Unfortunately a lock limits all actions except for flagging.

Migrated questions do get automatically deleted from the source site after 30 days. If you don't think the question should wait that long or, in this case, you want to burn a bad tag that's on it, you can always flag it to have a moderator come take care of it early. Just make sure you explain exactly what you want them to do and why.