# Comments on/edit migrated questions that are closed

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions, migrated-questions, migration-rejection

Why is it not possible to comment on/edit migrated questions (on the target site) that are closed as "too localized"?

Source on SO: [Latex get inputenc error including C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15301478/914686)

Source on TeX.SE: [Latex get inputenc error including C# code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101549/5764)

As far as I understand it, migrated questions are eventually erased from the source it's migrated from (SO in this case), leaving the question in a very poor state on the target site. By poor here I mean that no further discussion can ensue with the OP and the rest of the community.

Comment: Where are you trying to comment? The question is *locked* on TeX.SE because the migration got rejected (by being closed as too localized). You can only comment on it on SO.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug, then.  My screen on TeX.SE shows `migrated from stackoverflow.com 2 hours ago`
and 
`closed as too localized by egreg, tohecz, Kurt, lockstep, Werner 1 hour ago`

Comment: @animuson: Clarified in the post update. Comments (or edit) on the target site (TeX.SE in this case). As mentioned at the end of the question, it is my assumption that the source (on SO) is eventually erased. If this is the case, then what happens to the target (migrated) question?

Comment: @Gus: Yes, that is the case. You cannot comment on/edit the question on TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question is migrated, it's locked on the source site so that it can only be modified in its new home. The source version is eventually migrated. However, when the question is closed on the destination site, the situation is basically reversed because it's assumed that the destination site didn't want the question and the migration was invalid.

Closing the question on TeX "rejected" the migration. So now TeX is the proud owner of a migration stub that will get automatically cleaned up. It is locked, so no changes are possible. The original version of the question (on Stack Overflow) has been unlocked and closed as off-topic. It can be edited, commented on, etc.

Comment: And by "cleaned up" you mean that the target post (on TeX.SE) will be erased *in due time*? There's also just no reference to it being "locked", so it seemed buggy. I guess a gray-ed out "edit" implies "locked."

Comment: @Werner: In 30 days. The lock notice would be present in the revision history. I'm not sure why they don't display the red notice on the post itself. (Side-note: You can hover over the greyed-out edit link to see *why* you can't edit.)

Comment: @animuson Fun fact: it's actually 30 days either from when the question was asked or the migration date (I forget exactly which), which is a bit weird - if a question migrated, say, a few months ago ends up closed, it gets deleted nearly immediately.

Comment: @Werner That's a side-effect of being unable to display more than 2 banners below the post. One is getting used up by "migrated from" and the other is the closure notice. I agree that we should improve how this looks cause it's at best confusing as hell.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Should this be asked as a separate "feature request" question to clear up some migration/closed/locked notifications?

Comment: @Werner I am almost positive this has been asked before. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @Werner http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks. You're a search-deamon! Consider fixing this, which seems *specific* to TeX.SE: [Is full text search not working any more?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3355/5764)