# "closed w/o comment" auto-flag on closed migrated posts

Tags: bug, flags, closed-questions, migration

When a post is closed without a comment, a flag is auto-generated by the system:

> [image: "closed w/o comment"]

The issue is that the flag is still auto-generated on migrated posts that are closed w/o comment. [Migrated posts that are closed are locked on the site it is migrated to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171009/comments-on-edit-migrated-questions-that-are-closed), meaning that the flag cannot be acted on.

These flags should not be auto-generated on the site it is migrated to.

### Example:

Closed and Locked on the site it was Migrated to:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/will-a-short-cover-letter-get-my-resume-thrown-in-the-bin

Still Active on the pre-Migration Site:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223090/will-a-short-cover-letter-get-my-resume-thrown-in-the-bin?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. This should especially be easy now as the migrated questions already have differences from the normal closed, as is indicated by the [migrate] appended to the end of the question instead of [closed]. It's a small annoyance, but anything to have fewer pointless flags for the moderators is helpful.

This is even more annoying because I think that migrating a question should be done with few if any comments. I mean, do you really want to migrate a question with the comment "This would be a better fit for _____.SE". That seems kind of silly, that comment should just get flagged. The OP has a way to get more information, it really doesn't seem like it is required any more then it would be required with a duplicated question.

Comment: “migrated questions already receive special attention” — I must have missed something, what are you refering to?

Comment: I'm meaning that instead of the [closed] appended to the end of a closed question is shows [migrated]