# What posts are locked by Community?

Tags: discussion, migration, locked-questions, locked

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694376/1265154) to [a post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80183/optimization-without-an-algebraic-equation-in-python?noredirect=1) migrated from Stats.stackexchange.com to StackOverflow.

The answer was given on stats site, and migrated with the post. It is in locked and deleted state. What puzzles me, it is locked after receiving additional vote up (answer has +1 on stats and +2 on SO). And more, how it comes up being locked by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?

Surfing meta, it seems that I get what locked post is, and how and why some posts ends up being locked. But Community account seems to serve for automated maintenance tasks on stackexchange, so the quesition is, what triggered the mentioned answer locking?

Comment: I thought posts are locked when the question is migrated, so people don't post to the wrong thread.

Comment: @gunr2171 It seems your reasoning is correct, and I was perplexed by the migration note on SO, yet question being marked as offtopic invalidated migration.

Comment: See the answer on the linked question: answers to rejected migrations are locked and deleted.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging thanks, I indeed searched meta for the answer prior to posting this question, but was unable to find that piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althrough I did some research, and found some migrated questions marked as duplcates, there are no other similar instances, that is migrated questions put on hold as offtopics. So following is merely a guess and needs some justifications.

The difference seems to lie in the fact that [original question on Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80183/optimization-without-an-algebraic-equation-in-python) at the moment is not marked as migrated, but offtopic. So it is reasonable to conclude  that marking migrated question as duplicate invalidated migration, and consequently all migrated answers were automatically deleted, as main entry point to the questions is again on Stats site. May be locking along deletion is intended, may be it happened because additional votes and comments to the post were received, I can't guess.