# Why can I see the revision history of a deleted question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, revisions-list

I'm under 10k rep on Stack Overflow, so I can't see deleted content. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473143/methods-to-stop-software-piracy) from [a meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations). When I visit the question page, I get the standard removed for moderation reasons message. But when I visit [the revisions page for the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1473143/revisions) I'm able to see the revision history.

When I attempt to view revision history of other deleted questions, I get a 404 page as I would expect. It looks like this question has an interesting history being migrated, a community wiki and protected/closed/locked. Is this a bug? Or is this question special somehow?

Comment: The page you hit when something was migrated was changed recently. This could have been a missing test case.

Comment: Me too, and I'm even under 1000.

Comment: @MichaelT I have a feeling it's a bug, since I can't see [the timeline page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1473143/timeline). But wasn't completely sure because of the odd history of the question.

Comment: That's because the question was not deleted in any ordinary way. It's a "zombie", both dead and undead. :)

Comment: @StevenV I certainly think its a bug.  Just something that came out of the recent migration stub target which *used* to be a non-redirecting form of the page rather than the revision history.  The revision history *is* still useful, and since its at the other site not *too* important, unless its closed and deleted there too (and does the origin site get notified that it shouldn't show the history?).  There *was* some concern once about the rolling up of edits and lack of attribution (the CC license) to such edits at one point that *might* not be a bug but intended.

Comment: Related and possibly the cause/intent: [Does the migration of edited posts violate attribution requirements?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208904/does-the-migration-of-edited-posts-violate-attribution-requirements) - the change likely matches the status completed... and the dev answer: "So, as of today, anyone (regardless of rep) can link back to the original site's revision history on migrated questions, even if the question has been deleted on the original site." -- so by design then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit histories of migrated questions are available to everyone, even on deleted questions.  This insures that attribution does not get lost or obscured.  See [Does the migration of edited posts violate attribution requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208904/does-the-migration-of-edited-posts-violate-attribution-requirements/216280#216280)

In practice, this is probably not a real issue.  It's not like we're hiding the plans for the next stealth fighter behind a deletion, and casual browsing of deleted migrations is still prevented.

Comment: For clarification, the history is only available on deleted questions if it has been migrated. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Yup, can confirm that this is by-design so that attribution doesn't get lost if a migrated post is deleted on the origin site.