# Migration to per-site meta should not be reversed by closing or deletion?

Tags: bug, migration-rejection

On Gaming, we just had a strange situation where a question belonging on the meta was asked on the main site, so we closed it and migrated it to the meta. Then the OP deleted his question on the meta, so as per [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982), the question was unlocked on the main site and had to be re-migrated.

Since different questions belong on a main site vs. on a meta, and since migrations like this are within a single community, it's more likely that a question migrated in this fashion would be closed for some valid reason but still belong more on the target site than on the original site. Therefore it doesn't really make sense to have migration rejection in this case.

The posts in question are https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/69573/revisions and https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4720/revisions.

Comment: If you close/delete on the target the source question should be automatically reclosed as OT.

Comment: You can see this as "Migration Rejected". A moderator reopened and remigrated the question.

Comment: That's what I said at the end of my first paragraph. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to tell me

Comment: What I'm saying is that the history looks perfectly OK to me. The migration was rejected by the deletion so it's reclosed as OT. The mod comes along reopens and remigrates. I read the question as you saying that the question was left open by the rejected migration.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to say that migration rejection didn't work properly but that it shouldn't occur at all in the case of migrations between a site and its meta because it doesn't really fit with the initial reason for creating the migration reversal system

Comment: Ah. I see. Why shouldn't it occur? A question can be wrongly migrated to meta in the same way it could be wrongly migrated to another site.

Comment: @ChrisF I edited to try to explain my reasoning

Comment: I think if the user deletes their question on the target site, it should also delete the question on the original site *as a part of* the migration rejection.

Comment: @animuson I'm afraid not enough people will see that genius idea if you hide it in a comment.

Comment: Related: a question *closed* on the meta shouldn't be treated as a rejected migration, either.  We had a case today where the question was wrongly asked on main and migrated to meta, but then put on hold as unclear there.  It still belonged on meta, but mods had to intervene to unlock the meta question so it could be edited.  (Telling the OP in the close notice to edit to clarify and simultaneously preventing that edit makes it even worse...)