# Self delete on target side shouldn't reject a migration

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-questions, self-delete, migration-rejection

Aside from the giant mess of revisions, closes, migrations, reopen, reclose and delete that [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/303249/revisions) question is (sorry, 10k Programmers.SE link - though other parts may be visible in [the self deleted rejected post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855316/should-i-use-app-exec-or-app-exec-in-my-pyqt-application?noredirect=1), and a [wholesale rewrite of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22610720/revisions))... self deleting a post on another site shouldn't reject the migration.

The full order of events for this was:

1. Closed (off topic, migrate to SO) on P.SE (included OP's vote)
2. Closed (duplicate) on SO
   2a. OP edits another question to contain the text
   2b. OP deletes closed (dup) migrated post on SO. <-- *This rejects the migration*
3. Post unlocked on P.SE
4. Question reopened (including OP's vote)
5. Question closed *again* on P.SE
6. Question is self deleted on P.SE by OP

Aside from this being a bit more of a mess than the regular migration, the issue is that someone who self deletes a post on the target site that *hasn't* been closed in a way that rejects the migration (anything other than duplicate) will reject the migration.  Or phrased another way "if someone deletes a migrated post that is open or closed as a duplicate, the migration will be rejected."

This is a glitch in the intended functionality of the system. And as seen in this example, it caused more than a little bit of confusion about what is going on for anyone who hasn't actually dealt with migrations and created a rather poor user experience (self inflicted poor experience? maybe - poor experience none the less).

When a question is migrated and rejected *before* it is closed, this leads to a confusing experience - especially with the question getting what appears to be bounced around.

The bug fix is "simple" - don't reject the migration if the post is deleted before the migration is rejected.  If its off topic on the other site, or if it was closed as too broad or primarily opinion - yes, those reject the migration. But not the OP deleting the post before it is closed, or if it is closed as a duplicate. Its there - its not off topic on the site.

Or, as said some time ago (before he had the diamond - that's not an SE official position):

> I think if the user deletes their question on the target site, it should also delete the question on the original site as a part of the migration rejection. – animuson♦ [May 24 '12 at 18:25](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133524/migration-to-per-site-meta-should-not-be-reversed-by-closing-or-deletion#comment370573_133524)

There are other related questions to this that are quite close, though both specifically deal with migrations to their own meta:

- [Migrations can be unilaterally rejected by OP under certain conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247536/migrations-can-be-unilaterally-rejected-by-op-under-certain-conditions)
- [Migration to per-site meta should not be reversed by closing or deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133524/migration-to-per-site-meta-should-not-be-reversed-by-closing-or-deletion)

Comment: Well, I was the victim in this case. Looking forward a good solution from the core team.

Answer (score 3):

Special-casing author deletion here doesn't make sense to me; in cases where the question was indeed improperly migrated (as in, the author did not want it on the site where it was moved to), that's a pretty strong signal that it probably shouldn't have been migrated to begin with.

But there's an added wrinkle or two to the scenario that prompted this request, chief among them the fact that the question was a *duplicate* - this strongly suggests that the migration *was* appropriate. This is why closing as duplicate *doesn't* reject migrations, after all - the bug here was that deleting duplicates *did*. So [that's fixed as of yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127434/dont-reverse-migrations-on-deleted-posts-if-they-were-merged-first/329130#329130) - deleting questions closed as duplicates won't reject a previous migration.

Comment: Given your first paragraph here, can you please mark [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247536/migrations-can-be-unilaterally-rejected-by-op-under-certain-conditions) as by design?