# When does the community user delete a question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user, deleted-accounts

I just noticed that [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13789428/1048572), probably the same time the asker deleted his account (I can see a *User was removed* for the same timestamp in my rep log). I've seen [why does community user delete answers on close of question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138458/183280), but I don't understand why it happened in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The account got nuked along with all its posts ([another deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12852897/447356) and [yet another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12870149/447356)) which is weird, as he got some upvoted questions with upvoted answers which were not closed. Obvious loss of good content.

I know spammers eventually meet this fate by the hand of moderators, so maybe that user started to spam (or got his account hacked and used for spam) and moderator didn't notice it has valid posts as well.

Until official response will come, that's my best guess and $0.02.

[Cached copy of the poor user profile page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cToH5DhF1vkJ:stackoverflow.com/users/1733716/user1733716%20user1733716&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).

Comment: Ah, so an account got nuked by a mod? I had expected something like that, only I couldn't see what `Community` had to do with it - I'd liked to see the particular mod's name there

Comment: @Bergi In the general case: if a mod destroys an account rather than simply deleting it then *all* the associated posts get deleted (instead of just negatively scored ones). Any actions taken during deleting/destroying an account are attributed to Community ♦.

Comment: @Flexo valid and good content was deleted in this case... any reason for that?

Comment: I don't know the specifics on this one and I don't have access to audits.

Comment: @Flexo fair enough, thought moderator can see deleted user account and the reason why it got deleted.

Comment: The user profile 404 page is a hard 404 even with a diamond.