# Question migrated to a site shows as migration rejected, even though the question is still open

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, rejected-questions

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/480007/i-made-wordpress-multisite-and-now-everything-doesnt-display-properly) was originally (and incorrectly) migrated to WebApps (now [deleted](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/i-made-wordpress-multisite-and-now-everything-doesnt-display-properly), after closing it). Since the question was offtopic, I closed it there and as a result the migration on Super User was rejected.

I then proceeded to migrate it to WordPress - and now, even though the question is open on [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66406/i-made-wordpress-multisite-and-now-everything-doesnt-display-properly) - on Super User, [the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/480007/revisions) mentions that the migration to WordPress is rejected & hence doesn't show as "migrated".

What's going here?

(Note that the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/480007/revisions) shows migration to WordPress twice - that's because it was migrated by random first, but the question on Super User was shown as closed as offtopic instead of migrated - same issue as above.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was rejected the first time when you closed the question on WebApps, and rejected the second time when you *deleted* the question on WebApps.

Since both of those *are* [documented as actions that will reject a migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations), I'm inclined to consider this by-design.

I suspect (but don't particularly feel like verifying since there's more than enough noise surrounding that question already) that deleting the question on WebApps *before* you tried to re-migrate the question to Wordpress would've avoided this problem.

Comment: Does kind of seem like it should check that the rejection action came from the site of the latest Migrated Away before invalidating it, but...I'm not sure if this scenario is common enough to be terribly concerned. Do you know if the rejected migration to Web Apps not showing in the revision history is intentional, though?

Comment: @Tim: it is - they're *both* rejected migrations to Web Apps. There's apparently no check for a double- (or triple-) migration in that logic (which given that this was never really intended to be a supported operation probably makes sense - migrating *after* rejection should work just fine - though I'm curious if the deletion would've affected it in the same way). Note also that the migration history for the first migration was cleared before anything else happened, so... At least a half-chance it'd have messed up even if the check *was* there.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that the post was reopened on and remigrated from Super User without it having been rejected first on Web Apps? That is a rather messy situation. It still seems addressable, but "Just don't do that." seems reasonable then.