# Migration Procedure?

Tags: support, migration

I wrote a post on SO that seems to have been migrated to Code Review without my request or authorization:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas

Is there anyway to determine as the posts author who migrated it (or who voted it to be migrated)?

I don't really care, it got answered - but there was contention over whether it belonged on SO or CR as you can see in the comments - so I'm just curious as to what happened?

Can one moderator just make a unilateral decision and action a migration?  Or were there multiple votes involved?

Comment: Note: Technically you don't have the ability to authorize (or forbid) migrations and they can be done without your request.

Comment: @casperOne: There are six upvotes on a comment that explicitly says that we don't think it should be migrated and there was only one person that voted for it to be migrated.  In my opinion your decision was dubious, but as I said, I don't really care.

Comment: See first comment.  Performance is on topic for Code Review.  See their FAQ - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq.

Comment: @casperOne: "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?"  It's example code.

Comment: As long as the code is complete, and compiles, it fulfills that requirement.

Comment: @casperOne: See new comment in post: "Why on earth was this migrated here?" - as I said, bad call.

Comment: We can un migrate stuff.  There's little that's un reversible in this situation.  Monday-morning quarterbacking doesn't effect any of these changes though, just saying.

Comment: @casperOne: :) Sorry, I'm just being a mean old grump.  Do what you think is best.

Comment: It should be resolved in the next few hours, I'll check up on it when I can.

Comment: @casperOne `As long as the code is complete, and compiles, it fulfills that requirement.` Questions about complete and compilable code may also fufill SO requirements. The point is that it is an objective question about the code and not a request for a subjective _review_ of it. And only one non-mod person voted otherwise...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Which key optimizations to the C++ algorithm could get it on par with the BLAS version?"  Um, that's *exactly* what Code Review was made for.

Comment: @casperOne No, the question was, "Why does my implementation suck?" or "Why is A faster than B?" The latter being exactly the type of question that I like to answer on SO.

Comment: @casperOne: That bit is. _All_ of the rest is not. `Can anyone explain this difference? What exactly is the architecture of the BLAS implementation? I see it is calling fortran, but what is happening at the CPU level? What algorithm is it using? How is it using the CPU caches? What x86-64 machine instructions does it call? (Is it using advanced CPU features like AVX?) Where does it get this extra speed from?`

Comment: Full disclosure: I think it should be on SO but I think it should be _closed_ since it has about five million sub-questions

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Your opinion is ludicrous.  There was not one vote to close on SO after 500 views, the quesiton had 10 upvotes and 4 followers.  The "subquestions" are all elaborations on the central theme which is why is A 100 times faster than B.  A totally concrete question with a well researched background given.  Exactly the sort of stuff that should be on SO.

Comment: @user1131467: It is not nice to call someone's opinion "ludicrous" just because I'm possibly the only one who holds it out of 500 people. It was not a concrete well-researched question -- it was about twenty concrete well-researched questions. It was _far too broad_. Also you'll find that the question grew over time and most of those views did not see the full behemoth. The question needs some serious trimming to make it readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can one moderator just make a unilateral decision and action a migration? Or were there multiple votes involved?

Regular close voters can vote to close a question, or choose from a limited set of sites to migrate it to. Code Review is not an available migration path on Stack Overflow, however, so only a moderator may migrate a question to that site. A moderator's close/migrate vote is always binding (i.e. it overrides all others).

You can find out who performed the migration by scrolling to the bottom of your question where it was moved to, and clicking the origin site name:

> **migrated** from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas?noredirect=1)

Which brings you to the [original page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas?noredirect=1), where you can see at the bottom who migrated it:

> **migrated** to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas) by Luchian Grigore, casperOne♦

That said, a migration can be [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982); this involves closing the question on the destination site, which unlocks it on the originating site allowing it to be reopened if appropriate. However this depends on what happens to the question on the destination site.

Answer (score 3):

It says:

> migrated from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas?noredirect=1) 1 hour ago

below the question on the target site. Clicking on the link takes you back to the original question, where it says:

> migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com by Luchian Grigore, casperOne♦ 1 hour ago

Of these "Luchian Grigore" voted to close(he can't vote for migration to code-review since it's not in the list), and "casperOne" as a diamond mod migrated it.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the [mirgation stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas?noredirect=1) on Stack Overflow, you can see who closed it as off-topic.

Posts can be closed/migrated either by 5 users with enough reputation to close a quesiton (3k), by a single moderator, or by some combination (once a moderator votes to close, the question gets closed, whether there are no close votes already or 4).

In the case of your quesiton, the close notice reads:

> migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com by Luchian Grigore, casperOne♦ 1 hour ago