# If a question gets migrated, add a link to the new location in the original question

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions

If a question gets migrated, add a link to the new location in the original question

Example: https://superuser.com/questions/576435/how-to-send-to-twitter-and-facebook-at-same-time-tweetdeck-replacement

to

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42505/how-to-send-to-twitter-and-facebook-at-same-time-tweetdeck-replacement

Answer (score 1):

The example you give is a bit of a special case because [the migration was *rejected* on the target site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982). Basically, what happened was:

- Tony posted his question on Super User.
- Five users on Super User voted to migrate the question to Web Apps.
- A moderator on Web Apps closed the question.
- This rejected the migration, bouncing it back to Super User as if it had never been migrated in the first place.

That's also why you see the close reason on Super User listed as "off topic", just as if it had never been migrated but simply closed.

In these cases where migrations are rejected, it doesn't make much sense to link to a site where we know the question doesn't belong. If someone wanted to edit the question and/or nominate it for re-opening, they'd do all of that from the Super User side.

*Normally*, we do show a link in both directions. For example, [this question that was recently migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/577669/unable-to-install-software-from-a-cd-on-windows-8). There is a link that says "migrated from stackoverflow.com" on the SU side and the regular migration message ("migrated to superuser.com") on the SO side.

Comment: Coincidentally, I linked to that answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This already happens.

However, in this case, after it was migrated it was closed (but not as a duplicate) and thus rejected.

In such cases there is no point in showing the migration link as the question is not on topic for either site, so why bridge it?

Comment: Because the question can get comments and answers before it gets closed which can be useful to some people, at least to the question asker. So the question in either location is still useful. The mentioned question got comments in the new location.