# Why is this question locked

Tags: support, locked-questions

The following question which was migrated from stats.stack-exchange.com, has been locked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362242/book-bar-code-scanner

I tried to edit the question, because It could be written as

> How Can I scan and get information from a bar-code using an Android Device

In my opinion, the conceivable way that such a question can be closed is by `"exact duplicate"`, but It's not only been closed, but it's been locked.

According to [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), A post can be locked when

> - A question or answer where repeated voting or    editing is happening in a way which attempts to    game, hack, or otherwise abuse
>     the system.
> - A question that gets opened and    closed repeatedly many times without    achieving community consensus on    whether it should stay
>     open or    closed.
> - A question that, for    whatever    reason, continues to attract    flame    posts, spam, or other inappropriate answers.
> - A question that is repeatedly vandalized by its asker; for example, to drastically alter the meaning of the question that invalidates
>     existing answers, or to obliterate/obscure the question.

As far As I can tell, this question meets none of those criteria.

I can understand that the question was closed.  It wasn't formed very well and It was almost certainly a duplicate, but why Locked?

Comment: Questions that are closed after a migration [are locked by community](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16362242/revisions).. I don't *why* though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982 - that's what happen to rejected migrations.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that you shouldn't migrate low quality questions.  You should only migrate questions that are of high quality and will need little or no editing on the target site to be great questions.

When people start migrating crap just to get it off of their site then these target sites (i.e. the old programmers) end up just being a dumping bin filled with low quality questions.  Worse still, these questions can just end up being migrated around and around with everyone playing hot potato with these questions.

This is a mechanism to prevent those types of behaviors.  By locking questions that are closed after a migration it's a signal that you shouldn't be migrating a question unless you're sure that it will remain open on the target site; it also prevents the question from being migrated a second time.