# Make it clear why a migrated on hold question isn't available for editing

Tags: feature-request, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678846/no-of-words-in-a-string-using-java) was marked as being [on hold] and also migrated **to** stack overflow but not locked/protected. However it appears locked from editing/upvoting/adding comments on the stack overflow side

[image]

It also appears to still be active on programmers (but also [on hold]) with no mention of the migration:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205058/no-of-words-in-a-string-using-java?noredirect=1

Thanks to Joe's answer it is clear that this is because the question had the migration reversed after being closed as off topic. Can it be made clear in the banner on the question that it has no longer been migrated? (Or in fact just delete it)

Comment: I'm really curious why it's not just deleted outright - maybe that does happen every so often (how often does the automated process sweep to clean up deleted questions)?

Comment: @Joe Indeed; its behaving as if the question no longer exists but its showing me it anyway

Comment: @Joe I believe those are automatically deleted after 30 days.

Comment: Reading the [original post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982) linked in my answer, it looks like the /revisions should list the rejection (see ShaDoWizArd's answer) - but I can't see revisions for the post you link (it hasn't been edited, or I'm doing it wrong).  They discuss this issue in comments but it's not obvious any resolution occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The migration is automatically rejected due to being closed as generic off topic:
(see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982).)  When that happens, it's locked.  Perhaps that could be made more clear in the post with a message?

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the case; given that shouldn't there be some sort of indication that its been kicked on the question