# Community Diamond Moderator has locked & deleted multiple answers but why?

Tags: support, community-user, migration-rejection

On this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/how-to-maximise-chances-of-success-in-an-hr-interview) which was migrated from Programmers to the Workplace SE the [Community Diamond Moderator](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has locked and I assume deleted 4 answers on this question. These questions had a few good points in them that would help future users and I am not understanding why there were removed. Can I also point out that these are not my answers so this is not a complaint.

**Is anyone able to explain why this has occured please?**

These are two pictures but in the correct order as they appear on the question.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The post was closed on The Workplace, which [rejects the migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35744/allow-diamond-moderators-to-reverse-question-migrations/126982#126982). [Community](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is simply the system user that is associated with these kinds of automated processes, [among other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

Part of the rejection process is the deletion and locking of the previously-migrated answers on the original destination site. Likewise, those answers have been made available [on the original question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208488/how-to-maximise-chances-of-success-in-an-hr-interview?noredirect=1) again.

Comment: Worth to explain the community user isn't human. It's not trivial for new users or even veterans who never bothered to check in depth.

Comment: Fair point, added!

Comment: You guys don't believe in Santa but think the Community user isn't human? BWAAAAAAAAAAHAHAHAHHAAHA