# Request for migration reversal

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration

[How to use triggers with functions that require parameters from the spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52167/how-to-use-triggers-with-functions-that-require-parameters-from-the-spreadsheet) was incorrectly migrated from SO to WebApps.

The question is about Google Apps Script, is properly tagged, and is one of almost 5000 questions tagged [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). It's a javascript-based cloud programming environment - so while it's ALSO a web app, it's a clear fit for the mandate of SO. (Likely none of the voters have a single answer in [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).)

Also: Google [points people to StackOverflow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#questions) as their official support community. Given the mass of questions already there, it makes no sense to boot one or two over to WA.

(Is there any way to identify and bring back other similarly tagged questions that have been migrated?)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/172661 (As an aside, Google having linked SO as the official support community is meaningless if the question is off-topic. I could put a link to SO as the support site for my (fictional) web page on cooking recipes; that doesn't make recipe questions automatically appropriate for SO.)

Comment: @KenWhite - I accept your premise, I reject your conclusion. Yes, someone choosing to link to SO doesn't make that link appropriate. On the other had, being about a web service doesn't make it automatically inappropriate. That linking does steer users to SO, and since google-apps-script is a programming language, API and hosting service, it is on-topic for SO. Following a similar tautology, questions about programming for any cloud service are off-topic. (10K heroku, 7.5K Amazon Web Services, etc.) No, I think ignorance of the topic led to quick trigger fingers.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the question you linked. I was disputing your use of Google's linking having special meaning, which is the exact point I went on to make. Citing Google having linked to SO is irrelevant, regardless of the question being asked.

Comment: Gotcha - fair enough.